# FFmpeg works in linux and same command in windows get me error Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, linux

I have remote `index.m3u8` file and I want to download it with `ffmpeg`.
The contents file is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://example.com/encryption.key?x=AVCoPj..."
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.000,
https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...
#EXTINF:6.000,
https://example.com/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...
#EXTINF:6.000,
https://example.com/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...
#EXTINF:6.000,
:
:
```

I try this command in Windows and Linux:

```
ffmpeg -headers "User-Agent: a" -i "https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj..." -c copy "video.mp4"
```

In the linux all thing as well and the video downloaded. But on windows I get this error:

```
[AVIOContext @ 000001cef2816ec0] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Error when loading first segment 'https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...'
[AVIOContext @ 000001cef21c8f00] Statistics: 24167 bytes read, 0 seeks
https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Note: Also in the same windows on the chrome browser nothing problem with play this video URL and also can be download with `streamlink` software.(so not have any problem for network or blocking IP.)

You can see all logs:

**Log Windows:**

```
C:\>ffmpeg -headers "User-Agent: a" -i "https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj..." -c copy "video.mp4" -loglevel debug
ffmpeg version 2020-11-18-git-e3081d6f4f-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavcodec     58.112.103 / 58.112.103
  libavformat    58. 64.100 / 58. 64.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.102 / 58. 11.102
  libavfilter     7. 90.100 /  7. 90.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: a'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option 'video.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj....
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj....
[NULL @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 000001cef21bed80] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[https @ 000001cef21bed80] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header. Adding it.
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef21c1f80] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef21bed80] request: GET /index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Format hls probed with size=2048 and score=100
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES')
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[https @ 000001cef21bed80] Last chunk received, closing conn
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'https://example.com/encryption.key?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef2891bc0] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef2270900] request: GET /encryption.key?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef2269980] Statistics: 16 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef21eb740] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef282acc0] request: GET /seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef28992c0] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef21e2a80] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef282acc0] request: GET /seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef21c6d40] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef282bd40] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef2270900] request: GET /seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef226e6c0] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef282bec0] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef282acc0] request: GET /seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a

:
:
:

[AVIOContext @ 000001cef226b9c0] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef28dd1c0] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef282ba40] request: GET /seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef2817800] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Address 1.2.3.4 port 443
    Last message repeated 1 times
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Starting connection attempt to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[tcp @ 000001cef2270700] Successfully connected to 1.2.3.4 port 443
[https @ 000001cef2271600] request: GET /seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 000001cef2816ec0] Statistics: 368 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls @ 000001cef21be3c0] Error when loading first segment 'https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...'
[AVIOContext @ 000001cef21c8f00] Statistics: 24167 bytes read, 0 seeks
https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**Log CentOS:**

```
# ffmpeg -headers "User-Agent: a" -i "https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj..." -c copy "video.mp4" -loglevel debug
ffmpeg version 3.4.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument 'User-Agent: a'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option 'video.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj....
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj....
[NULL @ 0x2634700] Opening 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2635080] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[https @ 0x2635080] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x2635080] request: GET /index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Format hls,applehttp probed with size=2048 and score=100
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'https://example.com/encryption.key?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x26af660] request: GET /encryption.key?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 0x26af500] Statistics: 16 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x26af4e0] request: GET /seg-1-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=50
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] stream=0 stream_type=1b pid=100 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] stream=1 stream_type=f pid=101 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] stream=2 stream_type=15 pid=102 prog_reg_desc=
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 24167 bytes read:24167 seeks:0 nb_streams:3
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] All programs have pmt, headers found
[NULL @ 0x26aeb60] user data:"x264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=5 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=90 keyint_min=46 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=25.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=89 vbv_bufsize=102 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00"
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2c7f080] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2c7f080] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2c7f080] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2c7f080] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2c7f080] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] user data:"x264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=5 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=90 keyint_min=46 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=25.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=89 vbv_bufsize=102 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00"
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] Reinit context to 272x160, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x26dbc40] no picture
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] probing stream 1 pp:2500
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] Probe with size=7346, packets=1 detected aac with score=51
[mpegts @ 0x26b5680] probed stream 1
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] All info found
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Setting avg frame rate based on r frame rate
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 24167 bytes read:24167 seeks:0 frames:82
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...':
  Duration: 00:07:34.20, start: 0.101000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0, 21, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(left), 270x152 (272x160) [SAR 1:1 DAR 135:76], 0/1, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1, 61, 1/90000: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:2, 0, 1/90000: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449), 0/1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url video.mp4.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: video.mp4.
[file @ 0x2c403a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(left), 270x152 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 135:76], 0/1, q=2-31, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'; args=''
[AVIOContext @ 0x26b1dc0] Statistics: 138744 bytes read, 0 seeks
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2c93100] request: GET /seg-2-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 0x2c98f20] Statistics: 153784 bytes read, 0 seeksate=   0.1kbits/s speed=8.51x
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2c930e0] request: GET /seg-3-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 0x2c92c20] Statistics: 135736 bytes read, 0 seeksate= 175.1kbits/s speed=8.37x
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2c85260] request: GET /seg-4-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a

:
:
:

[AVIOContext @ 0x26cccc0] Statistics: 144760 bytes read, 0 seeksate= 172.4kbits/s speed=8.08x
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2c836a0] request: GET /seg-75-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 0x26ccec0] Statistics: 123704 bytes read, 0 seeksate= 170.0kbits/s speed=8.08x
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] HLS request for url 'https://example.com/seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...', offset 0, playlist 0
[hls,applehttp @ 0x2634700] Opening 'crypto+https://example.com/seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj...' for reading
[https @ 0x2c85da0] request: GET /seg-76-v1-a1.ts?x=AVCoPj... HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
User-Agent: a


[AVIOContext @ 0x26cccc0] Statistics: 84600 bytes read, 0 seeksrate= 172.4kbits/s speed=8.08x
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
frame= 6813 fps=122 q=-1.0 Lsize=    9873kB time=00:07:34.13 bitrate= 178.1kbits/s speed=8.14x
video:2506kB audio:7255kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.141788%
Input file #0 (https://example.com/index.m3u8?x=AVCoPj...):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 6813 packets read (2566107 bytes);
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 19556 packets read (7429357 bytes);
  Input stream #0:2 (data): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Total: 26369 packets (9995464 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (video.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 6813 packets muxed (2566107 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 19556 packets muxed (7429357 bytes);
  Total: 26369 packets (9995464 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x2c91480] Statistics: 2 seeks, 41 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x2c2d240] Statistics: 24167 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Why I can not download it on windows with ffmpeg and how can I resolve it?

**EDIT 1:** I tried [`ffmpeg N-54874-ga1553b0cfb-static (latest)`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) on `linux` and get same error! Then tried [`ffmpeg 3.4.2`](https://www.videohelp.com/download/ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static.zip) on `windows` and works well!
**So seem this is not related to the operating system. And seem this is a bug in newer version of `ffmpeg`!**

**EDIT 2:** I tried [many versions](https://www.videohelp.com/software/ffmpeg/old-versions) of `ffmpeg` for `windows`:

```
ffmpeg-1.0.1-win64-static           Error in the pull function.
ffmpeg-1.2-win64-static             Error in the pull function.
ffmpeg-2.0.1-win64-static           Error in the pull function.
ffmpeg-2.2.3-win64-static           Error in the pull function.
ffmpeg-3.0-win64-static             OK
ffmpeg-3.1.5-win64-static           OK warning...
ffmpeg-3.2.4-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-3.3.4-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-4.0.2-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-4.1.4-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static           OK
ffmpeg-4.3-win64-static             Error when loading first segment
ffmpeg-4.3.1-win64-static           Error when loading first segment
ffmpeg-2020-11-18-git-e3081d6f4f    Error when loading first segment
```

Seem after `>=4.3` there is a bug in ffmpeg!

**EDIT 3:**
I'm not sure if this is relevant; but apparently in all the cases where the test of versions failed, this skip warning appeared in the output:

```
[hls @ 000002794d99dcc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES')
[hls @ 000002794d99dcc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
```

Comment: First check with a current version on linux. get a git master build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: @Gyan I try `ffmpeg N-54874-ga1553b0cfb-static (latest)` on `linux` and get same error! Then try `ffmpeg 3.4.2` on `windows` and works well! So seem this is not related to the operating system. And seem is a bug in newer version of ffmpeg!

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Gyan Sure, I opened it: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8998